# amazon ec2 set max cost per month

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I see a lot of questions that are similar but no direct answer. I just want to play around with an instance to run some light hourly data aggregation and familiarize myself with the ec2 instances. I feel like I do not understand what my risk is however. Is there a way to set my max cost per month? I don't care if my instances get shutdown when the cost is hit, I just want limited liability for my experiment.

Also, running some monitoring of logs myself is not really a solution I will undertake for such a simple experiment. I just want to know if there is some easy way of limiting liability.

Comment: Just a pocket calculator would do, right. It's hour by hour, so no need for finegrained bookkeeping. Also, there is the free usage tier especially for experimenting.

Comment: I guess so ... but my understanding is that if it is in principle possible to write some awful thing that goes out of control and tries to download the entire internet, then it could get pricy right? Maybe I've completely misunderstood the bandwidth and storage on the free tier?

Comment: Bandwidth and storage will not be your main concern when dealing with EC2 (<-- note, not S3). The compute units are orders of magnitude more expensive than storage and bandwidth. Also, your AWS account has a usage report option that - AFAIR is usually very up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no, you wont be able to set a cap and stop services.

You can however easily monitor your costs. Starting with [billing alerts](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/05/10/announcing-aws-billing-alerts/). Account activity shows you a nearly realtime accounting of the costs you have occurred so far.

Comment: Cool, yes the billing alerts is pretty much enough once one is comfortable with the risk. I am probably overly conservative. As I haven't racked up any charges yet I'm not sure what the charging frequency is (hourly, weekly?) but I also have email and sms alerts on the credit card I used just to be safe.

Comment: You are billed once a month, usually just a few (3-5) days after the first of the month.